# Why does not the second parameter of GetProcAddress(HINSTANCE,LPCSTR) identify the function name? Why does something( "_Z6 * v" ) more added?

Tags: winapi, dll

/* This is part of code copied from http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/48TbqMoL/. */

//The functions declared in *.dll source code.

```
DLLAPI std::unique_ptr<Base> getObj(void);
DLLAPI std::string getName(void);
```

//The code to import functions from loaded library( which is named temp).
 What is "_Z6","v" in "_Z6getObjv"?

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> (__cdecl *ObjProc)(void);
typedef std::string (__cdecl *NameProc)(void);

ObjProc objFunc = (ObjProc)GetProcAddress(temp, "_Z6getObjv");
NameProc nameFunc = (NameProc)GetProcAddress(temp, "_Z7getNamev");
```

Comment: https://demangler.com/

Answer (score 3):

How the exported functions are named is compiler specific, see [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for more information. (`_Z*` is probably GCC v3+)

If you are building some sort of plug-in system you should have a public ABI with fixed function names. You can use a [.DEF file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx) to control the exported names.

With the Microsoft C/C++ toolchain you can also export a unmangled name with `EXTERN_C __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl MyFunc(long parm1) { return 0; }`

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what your functions are actually exported as.